# Solidity-How to get latest mined block's number and hash value?

Tags: blockchain, solidity

we can get the latest mined block's number and its hash inside `geth` as follows.

```
> eth.syncing.currentBlock
569367
> eth.getBlock(eth.syncing.currentBlock).hash
"0xac51e27c3fe38af1a0aeb2867a741ba6aa16780e435a586d934ccea3a71874b1"
```

is it possible to get the latest mined block's number and its hash? or should I keep an array inside my contract and when new block is mined, externally (`my_contract.addNewHash(<some_hash>`)) should I put its hash into my array for my contract to read from?

I have tried:
for example: `block.number`, `block.blockhash`, but I do face with following error:

```
Untitled:6:17: Error: Expected identifier, got 'Semicolon'
    block.number;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions are always executed in the block being mined. So, at any time, block.number will return the block height in which the transaction is being mined.

However, the hash of the block is not known until it is mined, and the output of transactions is part of the hash calculation, so the transaction has no access to the hash of the block being mined.

If this is any consolation, you can get the hash of the latest mined block, i.e. the one right before this block being mined with `block.blockhash(block.number - 1)`.

Try this:

```
contract Test {
    uint public blockNumber;
    bytes32 public blockHashNow;
    bytes32 public blockHashPrevious;

    function setValues() {
        blockNumber = block.number;
        blockHashNow = block.blockhash(blockNumber);
        blockHashPrevious = block.blockhash(blockNumber - 1);
    }    
}
```